# How does iPhone auto focus works

Tags: ios, iphone, image-processing

How works iPhone Camera auto focus ?
Is there a small motor that turn the mini lens ?
Does something move in the camera ? (lens or fluid or other ?)
Or is it a software image processing that gives us an auto focus.

Is there an API that can give us in real time focus length ?
When we take a picture, some exif fields gives us focal length. Is it possible to get this value by software without having to take a picture ?

Focus and focal length are the same thing ?

Comment: Check: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/31227/how-does-focus-work-on-mobile-phone-cameras

Comment: Is there a way to force this focus programmatically ?